# HTML <m>: what is it?

Tags: html, facebook

I recently tried to post a note on facebook where I wrote `P(Tn<M)`. It got terribly deformed. I eventually figured out `<m>` had to be some HTML command, so I fixed the issue by `P(Tn < M)`. I googled for [HTML `<m>`](https://www.google.it/search?q=html+%3Cm%3E&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=XcPYVPDlNMb1UPTkg-AM) and [HTML `<m>` command](https://www.google.it/search?q=html+%3Cm%3E+command&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=acPYVMuiMsT0UvWQhLAI) but didn't seem to find anything useful. So I come here and ask: what does `<m>` do in HTML? Is it an HTML command in the first place? Note: I know mostly nothing about HTML, but I *do* know that if I type `<m>` in here without the code markup it simply vanishes, and if I type it in a facebook note everything after it is lowercased and every word is made to be followed by `""=` or something like that, and at the end of the note an `</m>` appears. I *do* know that HTML often uses `<foo> </foo>` for things, so I think this *is* in fact HTML. Of course I don't know if facebook or SX use HTML, so that is a guess. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: dont know about facebook but you can create html element named m using javascript.. which you will decide how it is rendered..

Comment: Am i the only who started thinking what is a "HTML command"?

Comment: @Levente Nagy: The HTML [command](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/command.html#command) element is a multipurpose element for representing commands that was introduced with HTML5. ;-)

Comment: @user1438038 i was not talking about the "command element"....

Comment: Interesting to know @Naeem.

Comment: As for the other two who commented, I confess my utter ignorance on HTML so the terminology might be inappropriate or incorrect. Indeed, it seems the correct term is "tag", not "command".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated

Please see Patrick Hofman's answer as the link I have provided is no longer working. As others have suggested this is not a part of standard HTML 5 but may belong to some framework from ASP.NET or javascript.

### Old

"The  tag defines marked text. Use the  tag if you want to highlight parts of your text

Src: http://www.scriptcs.com/Lesson/tags/html5_m.asp.htm

It's an HTML 5 element.

(I typed `html m tag` in Google)

Comment: Let me try it out here: Let's see what is meant by «marked text»: <m> highlight this! </m>.

Comment: Won't be taken into account…

Answer (score 1):

The `m` element doesn't seem to exits in [the HTML4 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html), nor can I find it in [the HTML5 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#elements).

Despite that, I could find it [on some IBM site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-html5/):

> **mark**
>
> The m element indicates text that is "marked" somehow but not necessarily emphasized.

On the `mark` element can indeed be found something in the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element):

> The mark element represents a run of text in one document marked or highlighted for reference purposes, due to its relevance in another context.

Not sure if the `m` short widely supported, or even withdrawn from the standard. The fact there is not much to find about it isn't really comforting.

Answer (score 1):

this command doesnt seem to exist in html. facebook may used this as an angular JS command for more infos angularjs.org or 
http://aleaiactaest.ch/2012/07/29/build-your-own-html-element-with-angular/

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<em>Foobar</em>` tag to emphasize text, but no `<m>` tag. Maybe Facebook just strips any character that has a less-than sign directly preceeding? Did you try any other combination like `<x` or `<q`?

Comment: For the record I haven't.

Comment: Besides, it didn't strip the m, nor the space when I used `< M`. It altered the case of the letters and added `=""` or the likes after every word.